# ios ipsec vpn whitlist

Tags: ios, nevpnmanager

I was reading about the [VPN On Demand feature](https://support.purevpn.com/on-demand-vpn-for-ios) built on the latest versions of iOS.

**The problem here is**：I run vpn in my app, other app can use the vpn traffic. Now,I hope that only some domain names can use vpn, such as only google.com,other normal.

```
NEVPNProtocolIPSec *protocol = [[NEVPNProtocolIPSec alloc] init];
... other setting ...
NEProxySettings* setting = [NEProxySettings new];
setting.excludeSimpleHostnames = YES;
setting.HTTPSEnabled = YES;
setting.HTTPEnabled = YES;
setting.autoProxyConfigurationEnabled = YES;
NSMutableArray *blackList = [NSMutableArray new];
[setting setExceptionList:blackList];

NSArray *whiteList = @[@"google.com"];
[setting setMatchDomains:whiteList]; 

[protocol setProxySettings: setting];
```

But it did not work.
Please any HELP!